# Pointers in C(printing address why not ASCII value)?

Tags: c

```
char *b[]={"ab","cde"};
char c[2][3]={"cc","dd"};
printf("%s\n%s\n",b[0],b+1);
printf("%s %d address=%d\n%s\n",c,c,&c,c[1]);
```

This is my snippet. and the output I got is

```
ab
s@
cc 2110475296  address=2110475296
dd
```

**My question is:** when we are printing the values of array c using letter 'c' for '%s' it is printing string that is ok, but when we use '%d', it should print the ASCII value of the string but it is printing address why?

Comment: `%d` is for printing integers, why do you think it should print the ASCII value of the string? It interprets the address `c` as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

`c` is not a `char`; it is (passed as) a *pointer to arrays* of `char`.  And the underlying value of a pointer is *typically* the address it points at.

For reference, though, you could have caused the universe to implode by passing `printf` args with types different than you told it you were passing.  Don't do that.